# how can we prove the quantum oracle gates are equivalent. Ox with input |x,b⟩ returns |x,b⊕f(x)⟩ and Oz with input |x⟩ and returns(−1)^f(x)|x⟩

Tags: quantum-gate, oracles

[image]

where

[image]

How can we prove these two quantum oracles are equivalent:
$$O_x:|x,b\rangle\mapsto|x,b\oplus f(x)\rangle$$
and
$$O_z:|x⟩ \mapsto(−1)^{f(x)}|x⟩$$

Comment: They're not based on the information you provided. I feel like there's some missing context here.

Answer (score 1):

The two oracles are not equivalent.  But if you have either one of these oracles, you can trivially construct the other. In that sense they are equivalent.

Converting a phase oracle into a standard oracle is discussed [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/23600/construct-a-standard-oracle-using-a-phase-oracle).

To convert a standard oracle into a phase oracle is discussed in the Wikipedia article on [Grover's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm).  Put $|-\rangle$ into the "result" qubit before running the algorithm.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!

Comment: @venki If the answer helped you/solved your problem, please remember to upvote it and mark it as accepted! :)

Comment: Surely conversion from phase into standard *only* works of you've got a *controlled* version of the phase oracle? So if you've only got the non-controlled version, that doesn't help with an equivalence claim?